# How to connect my Mac Mail to my domain which his DNS are handled through DigitalOcean?

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, digital-ocean, mail-server

I bought a domain.

I pointed his name servers to:

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
```

I have added a `CNAME` record point to `@`

I want to send and receive emails using my Mac mail program.

I know that I should probably build a full mail server which is an awful thing to do.

Therefore, I have another server (not digitalocean) running on cPanel. In this cPanel I have a very powerful cPanel's mail server.
How can I point my digitalocean `CNAME` to the remote server where the cPanel is?

I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your domain points to the digital ocean server, you will have to create `A record` that points to the IP of that server, same goes to any subdomain.

Regarding your mail server, you need to make `mail.mydomain.com` points to the IP of your cPanel server using `A record` not `CName` and also modifying other records like `SPF/DKIM records`.

For your local mail client you can get the configuration by logging into the cPanel user account and view the mail settings

Comment: What do you mean modify MX record as the mail settings showed by your cpanel account? Should I add a MX record in DigitalOcean with `@` as name or `example.com` or `mail.example.com`?  In my cPanel account I have only one MX record which is name is: `example.com.` and `Priority: 0
Destination: example.com`

Comment: @Raz, Sorry I wrote it by mistake, just start and make `mail.example.com` points to the mail server, then login into the cPanel account (not the WHM account) and check the configuration that should be made to your local mail client

Comment: That means that in Digital Ocean I should just point A record to mail.example.com with the MX record?

Comment: the a record of mail.example.com should point to the IP of your mail server, also the mx record should point to that mail server

Comment: I don't understand. Should I create MX record in Digital Ocean, and the value of the name server is the IP of the server that has the cPanel account?